# Javascript innerHTML not changing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a simple dashboard and i want to change the section part of the pages. to change this i used innerHTML. but when i run it the UI is not changing and the value in the console is not changing as well.

what i want to do is to change content of the pages with `html` files and not touch the sidebar. what i'm getting is it doesn't change it but when i use it int the URL tag it works and when clicked after many click it works sometimes.

the Javascript file. is as follows

```
const route = (event)=>{
    event = event || window.event;
    event.preventDefault();
    window.history.pushState({}, "", event.target.href);
    routeHandler();
};
const routes = {
    404: "/html/404.html",
    "/": "/html/home.html",
    "/school" : "/html/school.html",
    "/student" : "/html/student.html"
};
const routeHandler = async ()=>{
    const path = window.location.pathname;
    const route = routes[path] || routes[404];
    const html = await fetch(route).then((response)=> response.text());
console.log(html);
    document.getElementById("main-page").innerHTML = html;
};
```

my `index.html` body

```
<div class="sidebar">
...
<li>
                <a href="/" onclick="route()">
                    <i class='bx bx-grid-alt'></i>
                    <span class="link_name">Dashboard</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="sub-menu blank">
                    <li><a href="#" class="link_name">Dashboard</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
...
</div>
...
<section id="main-page"></section>
    <script src="/script/router.js"></script>
    <script src="/script/index.js"></script>
```

other pages are as follows

```
<div class="content">
        <h1>Course Section</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed rem non doloribus voluptatibus perferendis alias ea ratione nulla inventore beatae exercitationem totam velit assumenda enim vitae, fugiat molestias rerum nemo?</p>
    </div>
```

so why is this not working?

Comment: I don't think what you are trying to do is possible using `vanilla JS` without `iframe`.

Comment: Instead of creating different `html` pages create different `divs` and show hide them based on user selection. Else you can `react`.

Comment: What's in the dev console if you hit F12?

Comment: @Matt it shows `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
` in `route.js:1` and other `[Intervention] Slow network is detected.`

Comment: @KunalTanwar but what doesn't make sense is that when i click it at random it shows the page. like when clicking it many times. and sometimes it doesn't even work. it changes once and after many clicks and many tries it changes it but it's random. why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using XML HttpRequests.
**Basic example** to understand how it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<body>
<div id="sidebar">
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc('A.txt')">Change Content A</button>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc('B.txt')">Change Content B</button>
</div>
<div id="main-page">

</div>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(chosen_option) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("main-page").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", chosen_option, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This way all "dashboard" stay same, but browser gets only content for "main-page" div.

You need to have content files (in this example A.txt and B.txt).
In content files you should put content for main div.

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting iframe src with your javascript and style it appropriately.